# Как узнать серийный номер диска в java?

Tags: java, диск

Мне нужно узнать серийный номер диска используя `java`, как можно это сделать? В `python` можно использовать `pywin32`, есть ли что-то похожее для `java`?

Comment: Что за диск, CD-ROM? Какая ОС?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для Windows можно вызвать команду [`wmic`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic): `wmic diskdrive get serialnumber`:

```java
String sc = "cmd /c" + "wmic diskdrive get serialnumber";

Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sc);
p.waitFor();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()))) {
    String line;

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    } 
}

System.out.println("HDD Serial number: " + sb.substring(sb.toString().lastIndexOf("r") + 1).trim());
```

Answer (score 2):

С помощью библиотеки [OSHI](https://github.com/oshi/oshi) (Operating System and Hardware Information library for Java) серийные номера можно вывести так:

```
SystemInfo info = new SystemInfo();
info.getHardware().getDiskStores()
        .stream()
        .map(HWDiskStore::getSerial)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```